# node js function.then in not a function using q

Tags: node.js, promise, q

Hello its so wired i am trying to do async function but when i use it i get error

using q 
on package json
`"q": "^1.4.1"`

```
TypeError: helper.setNextUserNewsAction(...).then is not a function
```

this is my helper

```
module.exports = function() {
  return {
    setNextUserNewsAction: setNextUserNewsAction
  }
}();

function setNextUserNewsAction(minutesToSet){
    var defer = q.defer();
    var x = minutesToSet;
    var d = new Date();
    var nextNews = new Date(d.getTime() + x*60000);
    var minutes = nextNews.getMinutes();
    var newMinutesToSet = 0;
    for (var i = 0 , j = minutesToSet; j <= 60; i+=minutesToSet,j+=minutesToSet) {
        if (minutes > i && minutes < j)
            return newMinutesToSet = (i % 60);        
    }
    nextNews.setMinutes(newMinutesToSet);
    nextNews.setSeconds(00);
    var NextNewsAction = {
        AccessDate: nextNews,
        Type: 'News',
        Current: 1
    }
    defer.resolve(NextNewsAction);
    return defer.promise;        
}
```

and when i call this function in my controller it send me that error

```
var helper = require('../helpers/playlist');
helper.setNextUserNewsAction(15).then(function(action){
     console.log(action);
},function(err){ 
     console.log(err);
});
```

i have also  try doing that with try and catch and still same error
well its not the first time or the 20 i am using q
hope somebody can help

Comment: `return newMinutesToSet = (i % 60)`

Comment: $q give the same error
what about that return? its returning from the loop

Comment: That return doesn't return a promise, hence no `.then`.

Comment: It is returning from the function, not the loop. You want break;

Comment: @robertklep can explain moreplease?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning something from the for loop:

```
for (var i = 0, j = minutesToSet; j <= 60; i += minutesToSet, j += minutesToSet) {
    if (minutes > i && minutes < j)
        return newMinutesToSet = (i % 60);
}
```

So the `setNextUserNewsAction` function is not returning a promise, therefore there is no `.then()`.

Try this:

```
var q = require('q');

module.exports = function() {
    return {
        setNextUserNewsAction: setNextUserNewsAction
    }
}();

function setNextUserNewsAction(minutesToSet){
    var defer = q.defer();
    var x = minutesToSet;
    var d = new Date();
    var nextNews = new Date(d.getTime() + x*60000);
    var minutes = nextNews.getMinutes();
    var newMinutesToSet = 0;
    for (var i = 0, j = minutesToSet; j <= 60; i += minutesToSet, j += minutesToSet) {
        if (minutes > i && minutes < j) {
            newMinutesToSet = (i % 60);
        }
    }
    nextNews.setMinutes(newMinutesToSet);
    nextNews.setSeconds(00);
    var NextNewsAction = {
        AccessDate: nextNews,
        Type: 'News',
        Current: 1
    }
    defer.resolve();
    return defer.promise;
}
```